# Coldfusion 2016 - "Advance Scheduling support is not available in this edition of ColdFusion server."

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-2016

I am receiving the titled error message when trying to use cfschedule in Coldfusion 2016.

I found an old issue from 2012 on the Adobe forms (https://forums.adobe.com/message/4560283#4560283) for this same error happening in Coldfusion 10 (it was a bug that was fixed in an update). However, I am running Coldfusion 2016 Standard and I cannot find any answers about this issue for this version.

If it matters, I am calling cfschedule via script as follows:

```
cfschedule( action="update", task="Task1", interval="60", mode="application", starttime=timeFormat(dateAdd("s", 30, now()), "HH:mm:ss"), URL="<MY URL>", eventHandler="com.SearchTaskHandler" );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not supported in CF standard.

The specific part is the mode. `mode="application"`

You are using application and application specific schedules are not supported in Standard Edition

http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html